# How to read multiple strings in a file as a different variables

Tags: file, shell, variables, unix, scripting

I have a conf file content like below.

file.conf:

```
key name
value pswd
```

Now I want write a script to having two variable like above

script.sh

```
key="name"      #key as variable
value="pswd"    #value as variable
```

. /path/to/file.conf is giving me :- key & value command not found error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `declare`:

```
while read k v; do
   declare $k="$v"
done < file.conf
```

Then test these values:

```
declare -p key
declare -- key="name"

declare -p value
declare -- value="pswd"
```

Comment: There is no "declare" in some shells (e.g. dash). You could replace declare line with: eval "$k"="$v".

Comment: Right, this is BASH specific. For old Bourne shell use eval

Comment: Hi Anubhava, thanks for your quick solution. Just have a small query- If my file.conf has some commented lines then it's giving me following error with your code:-

File.conf

     ##
     #
     #
     key name
     value pswd

Output:-

./test.sh: line 2: declare: `##=': not a valid identifier
./test.sh: line 2: declare: `#=': not a valid identifier
./test.sh: line 2: declare: `#=': not a valid identifier

Comment: If i use "eval" instead of "declare" then its not giving my any error for the above mentioned example. But if the file.conf file has a blank line then it gives an error "./test.sh: line 3: =: command not found". Also if a line has a path for a file, then it gives an error "No such file or directory". Please suggest something on this.

Comment: @user3527785 You didn't mention that in your original question; please open a new question for such a drastic addition.

Comment: @chepner why do you need a separate question for small modification? Main question can be edited.

Comment: Questions should be edited to clarify minor points; your addition adds an entirely new element to the question.

Comment: done.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595180/read-multiple-strings-from-a-file-as-a-different-variables