# Read multiple strings from a file as a different variables.

Tags: file, shell, scripting

In continuation of [How to read multiple strings in a file as a different variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33592811/how-to-read-multiple-strings-in-a-file-as-a-different-variables/33593014#33593014) :-

file.conf:

```
####
#xyz

key name


/usr/bin/ /text/abc/

value pswd
```

Now I want write a script to having two variable like above

script.sh

```
key="name"      #key as variable
value="pswd"    #value as variable
/usr/bin/=/text/abc/
```

Please refer to above mentioned link for more info.

Comment: Variable name cannot be `/usr/bin/` as `/` is not allowed in variable names.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a way to ignore the lines with invalid entry for a valid unix variable name. A unix variable follows this rule:

> start with underscore or an alphabet followed by 0 or more alphanumeric or underscore

Using this rule you can use this script in BASH:

```
while read k v; do
   [[ $k =~ ^[_[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*$ ]] && declare $k="$v"
done < conf.file
```

This will ignore all the blank lines or lines starting with # or `/usr/bin` etc.

In ksh try this:

```
while read k v; do
   [[ $k =~ ^[_[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]*$ ]] && eval $k="$v"
done < conf.file
```

Comment: is there anyway to assign /text/abc/ to /usr/bin/  &  echo to verify this?

Comment: As I commented above also that `/text/abc/` is not a valid unix variable name